# Finding the set for which a function is defined

Tags: complex-analysis

The function definition is as follows:

$ f(z) = $ the unique v such that $|v-z|=|v-u|=|v|$ for some fixed $u=a+ib$.

For this question, I'm able to understand the basic geometry of the question and understand intuitively that it should not be defined everywhere. As of now, I've only found appropriate values for $v = f(x,y)+i*g(x,y)$ (which is also in terms of $a$ and $b$).

For reference, the values I've found:

$f(x,y) = \dfrac{x^2b-y^2b-ya^2-yb^2}{4bx-4a}$

$g(x,y) = \dfrac{a^2+b^2-(ax^2+y^2ba-ya^3-yb^2a)}{4b^2x-4ab}$

The problem though is that these calculations don't seem to hint at any domain being undefined, which leads me to believe it was unnecessary to calculate (I do suspect also that I've made an error in my algebra).

To get an idea of what I'm solving, I've drawn a fixed point u=a+ib on the cartesian plane. Then, for some arbitrary z=x+iy, a line that is equidistant between said z=x+iy and u=a+ib. Then what I'm trying to find is the v on this line that satisfies the relation that its distance from z and u is the same as its modulus. But even this is giving me troubles as nothing appears obvious.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your condition as $$|v-z|=|v-u|=|v-0|$$This means that $v$ is the point at equal distances from $z$, $u$, and $0$. If $u\ne kz$ with $k\in \mathbb R$, then $v$ is the circumcenter of the triangle with vertices $z$, $u$, and $0$. Obviously, if the three points are collinear, you might have a problem to find the circumcenter, or find a unique solution.

Also note that you might have some errors in your calculations. For both $f$ and $g$ I've got expressions with $ay-bx$ at the denominator. This also hints that there might be a problem when $ay=bx$ or if you want, when $\frac ax=\frac by=k$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Remember that $$|z-\alpha| = |z-\beta|$$ is a set of $z$ that are equaly apart from $\alpha $ and $\beta$ i.e. perpendicular bisector of segment between $\alpha $ and $\beta $. So $f(u) =$ circumcenter of triangle $\Delta u0z$.

Does it help?